# Quickblox: Read status not received

Tags: json, quickblox

We are using the latest Jars/SDK for read/delivered statuses and web-service to send messages across all platforms Android/iOS/Web.
I am sending the message as `SetMarkable(True)` but it is received as `false` on both sides.

If I reload all messages from Quickblox server, then I can see that all messages have Read/Delivery Ids as per requirement but markable property is "0"/false.

**Here are few details regarding how the chat works:**
We open chat screen and load our old chat. We can create chat with one user multiple times based on product, so in order to meet this requirement we made a group dialog with chat as private. While posting a message, we first send message to group and then to private chat. Also to note that we are using custom parameters.

In android

**This is our json for posting info into group dialog:**

```
      JSONObject jsonChild1 = new JSONObject();

      //jsonChild1.put("id", id);
      jsonChild1.put("chat_dialog_id", chat_dialog_id);
      jsonChild1.put("message", message);
      jsonChild1.put("send_to_chat", send_to_chat);
      jsonChild1.put("markable", "1");
      jsonChild1.put("product_id", productId);

      Utility.showLog("Json String is", "" + jsonChild1.toString());...
```

This is our json for posting info into group dialog and in return we get response where our markable value is 1. However, when we re-get history its markable value is 0 although `readId`'s and `deliverId`'s work correctly.

**For Posting data in private :**

```
      JSONObject jsonChild1 = new JSONObject();

      //jsonChild1.put("id", id);
      jsonChild1.put("send_to_chat", send_to_chat);
      jsonChild1.put("markable", "1");
      jsonChild1.put("product_id", productId);
      jsonChild1.put("grp_msg_dialog_id", chat_dialog_id);
      jsonChild1.put("save_to_history", "1");
      jsonChild1.put("recipient_id", otherUserChatId);

      jsonChild1.put("message", message);
```

While webservice is same - "https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Message.json" for both, the difference is in parameters.
Also, in old jars we had `processMessageDelivered` and `processmessageRead` but in new jars we tried applying new class which is Message `StatusListener` but it isn't working also. The demo with new jars doesn't include any information corresponding to message status. Message status worked in old jars where I received message delivery status only  and not message read... as markable value is "0" or false every time.

**UPDATE**: We need the markable property in callbacks, for example for the following code to work:
In android:

```
@Override
    public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat chat, QBChatMessage message) {

        if(message.isMarkable()){
            try {
                privateChat.readMessage(message.getId().toString());
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

QuickBlox uses **markable=1** only in a real time messages to notify other user that a sender would like to receive the statuses about message he sent.

There is no field called **markable** in messages from REST API.

If you use read and delivered statuses in your application then you can just check the **readIds** and **deliverIds** fields and if there is no your ID in array then just send read or delivered statuses.

**UPD**

I tested it via hurl

Here is my request
http://hurl.quickblox.com/hurls/8c003dc3d6600c1c45e646f85e66e83d1d12dc5b/a6c1ba9a6ecc60de38525124639ae8828036f43c

And here is what I received on Android

```
11-24 08:50:59.417 13621-14361/com.sdk.snippets I/Snippet: received 
message: QBChatMessage{id=56548243a0eb474de5000041, sender_id=5179221,
 recipient_id=5179218, body=blablabla, properties=
{dialog_id=55ed5c7e05244fbde8c45e83,   message_id=56548243a0eb474de5000041,
 save_to_history=1, date_sent=1448378947}, attachments=[],
 dialogId=55ed5c7e05244fbde8c45e83, dateSent=1448378947, markable=true,
 readIds=null, deliveredIds=null} from user: 5179221, dialogId:
 55ed5c7e05244fbde8c45e83
```

As you can see markable=true here

Comment: I am using **readIds** and **deliverIds** to display read status, but we need to check markable property for callbacks used in QuickBlox. i.e for **processMessageDelivered** which cannot be done without markable property. Please check update in above question for code example where markable is required for the following function: **privateChat.readMessage(message.getId().toString());**

Comment: If you set markable to 1 then it will be true inside 'processMessage'. You say it doesn't work?

Comment: **processMessage** markable value is returned as false even if we set value as true.

Comment: Did you check? And is it a bug?

Comment: We stated this before. 

The response does show markable true, but when we retrieve chat messages that time markable value is false.

When we set markable as true that time it shows it true but when we fetch chat messages it returns them false. 

Also, on **ProcessMessage** callback we receive it as false although we are setting it 1